# android Webview goes back two pages?

Tags: android, webview, tabs, fragment

*When i press the back key the webbview goes back two pages and not one*

I have two tab fragments and each tab has one webview for website1 and website2
each webview's onkeylistener has this code

```
mWebView.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {

        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && mWebView.canGoBack()) {
                mWebView.goBack();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

    });
```

but it goes back twice

Comment: if you are using a viewpager make sure to only catch that event on the current tab, otherwise it will handle both and you will get back twice.

Comment: your using view pager in your application to control fragments ?